# updating one table with the value of another table and the two tables are in seperate database

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables in my two databases. The two tables columns are same. So I need to update table1 data to table2. But the two tables are in two databases.
Currently I have the query to update data in the same database.

UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CODE = Table2.CODE
SET Table1.Marks = [Table2].[Marks];

This query is successfull in the same database. But Now I have two databases in location MyDocuments in C.
Database1 and Database2. So How can I do it two databases, update Table1 data from Database1 to Table2 in Database2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Database1 link (attach) Table2 from Database2, and your query will run as before.

Go to menu External Data, Access and link the table using the wizard.

Comment: Sir could u pls explain

Comment: Thank you sir for ur help, Sir I have another problem with the same issue, I have two tables with the same name in two databases. So how can I do that,    UPDATE Entry INNER JOIN Entry ON Entry.CODE = Entry.CODE SET Entry.Marks = [Entry].[Marks];  Here two tables name is entry.

Comment: You just link it as before. The linked table will be assigned a name like _Entry1_ which you can change if you prefer. Now use this name in your query.